# pushing to solidity structure array fails to increase array length

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I'm trying to create an structure array with three elements. When running this code upon deploying a contract, sometimes the middle fish gets somehow overwritten by the last fish. We observe then that the `fishies` array becomes length two instead of three. When observing the `Release` event we see two releases with the same `fishId`.

The javascript code to deploy in truffle migrate looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  const coo = accounts[0];
  deployer.then(async() => {
    let fishery = await Fishery.deployed();
    await Fishery.releaseFish(1, 1, 200, AUCTION_DURATION);
    await Fishery.releaseFish(2, 1, 200, AUCTION_DURATION);
    await Fishery.releaseFish(3, 1, 300, AUCTION_DURATION);
  });
};
```

The solidity code defining the structure and the function looks like this:

```
Fish[] fishies;

function releaseFish(
    uint128 _id,
    uint32 _category,
)
    returns (uint)
{
    Fish memory _fish = Fish({
        id: _id,
        category: _category
    });

    uint256 newFishId = fishies.push(_fish) - 1;
    Release(
        newFishId,
        uint128(_id),
        uint32(_category)
    );
}
```

The Release events coming out with a duplicated `fishId = 1` event.

```
Release(0,1,1)
Release(1,2,1)
Release(1,3,1)
```

or in detail:

```
Release event:[  
   {  
      "logIndex":0,
      "transactionIndex":0,
      "transactionHash":"0x2c48a2f9e5959f13a176d24d7f832ecf405ddd732e7d0f0d6e2f12bdde1cf7b6",
      "blockHash":"0xfe1bf47d71f0be3e921fe1df796b73befdf5f914b218684b2ae07ec4c45e4e9b",
      "blockNumber":9,
      "address":"0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10",
      "type":"mined",
      "event":"Release",
      "args":{  
         "owner":"0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57",
         "fishId":"0",
         "id":"1",
         "category":"1"
      }
   },
   {  
      "logIndex":0,
      "transactionIndex":0,
      "transactionHash":"0x4983b107c7529bd96db6332c1a6980f3370b5805a1956f64c16c39c8a7ad62d5",
      "blockHash":"0x9cb5b5670ec29af38d3b84d6e0bd35f283a95b1f3bc7546f1ca1c349918aaf96",
      "blockNumber":10,
      "address":"0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10",
      "type":"mined",
      "event":"Release",
      "args":{  
         "owner":"0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10",
         "fishId":"1",
         "id":"2",
         "category":"1"
      }
   },
   {  
      "logIndex":0,
      "transactionIndex":0,
      "transactionHash":"0x20a61f53fd21c1eacc6a3fadece9992a3926448c65d6f372f9653d7bc760a088",
      "blockHash":"0x67e07b72ee4c29daa28923dbf26735830c438af88b59825006851b8dc6ccbc70",
      "blockNumber":11,
      "address":"0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10",
      "type":"mined",
      "event":"Release",
      "args":{  
         "owner":"0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10",
         "fishId":"1",
         "id":"3",
         "category":"1"
      }
   },
]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't happen entirely consistently. Running it on a different computer, with different arrangements, or just randomly sometimes it runs fine.

Note that I've simplified this a bit from our actual code - but I'm hoping it captures the necessary elements to discuss the issue.

System: Running truffle migrate on Ganache, the transactions for each appear on separate blocks.

Comment: To make sure I'm reading your description correctly, have you verified that the state of your contract is incorrect as well? Some of the first things I would check are how I've set up my event watchers (to make sure I'm not seeing duplicate events from the same block number) and make sure the object in the event callback doesn't have `removed` set to `true` (from an orphaned or failed transaction).

Comment: Excellent comment. I have updated the question to include the (complete?) log to make the situation more clear.
I would love to check if the callback has `removed` set to `true` ... after much searching I asked another question about how to do that!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554681/how-to-access-ethereum-event-objects-specifically-the-removed-element-to-test

Comment: I am new to all of this, but I thought I remember reading that arrays had to be a static length.

Comment: Arrays of structures are allowed to change in size unlike normal arrays.